# What kind of 'int' to use in numpy arrays?

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy, cython

When passing an integer array to a C function from numpy, what is the right type of `int` to use? If the C functions expects an array of plain `int`, then:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3])
```

seems incorrect since it can generate `np.int32_t` type arrays that are basically `long int`s?

is this the correct form instead?

```
A = np.array([1,2,3], np.dtype("i"))
```

i'd like to avoid accidentally passing something like a `long int` when C expects `int`. should all the C code I write expect `long int` types in numpy arrays?

**UPDATE** To give concrete example, if the Cython function is:

```
cpdef int[:] test_func(int[:] arr, int[:] result):
    cdef int i = 0
    for i in xrange(arr.shape[0]):
    result[i] = arr[i] + 1
    return result
```

then this seems correct:

```
import numpy as np
input = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.dtype("i"))
result = np.empty(input.shape[0], dtype=np.dtype("i"))
test.test_func(input, result)
```

but if you substitute `dtype=np.dtype("i")` for `dtype=int` then it complains that:

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'long'
```

Comment: `int32_t` is `long int` only in 32-bit memory model (ILP32). Under LP64 (64-bit), `long int` would be an `int64_t` (but `int` would remain `int32_t` same as with ILP32). So `int` for the C code seems a good choice.

Comment: @isedev: but what is a good choice or the `dtype` of the passing numpy array?